# Can I create Excel formulas for my add-in to feed in values to the add-in to work with?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I want to grab time series data from a rest server and insert it into a spreadsheet, and also be able to upload data from the spreadsheet to the server.

At the moment, I have a VBA solution which loops over the cells up- or down-loading the values it finds.

This is seriously error-prone and the amount of validation code is growing and growing.

I'd like to create a formula on an add-in which takes the symbol cell and the date/time cell and displays the data point from the time series, a bit like this with the symbol in B2 and the date/times in col A:

```
=getDataPoint(B2, A7)
=getDataPoint(B2, A8)
=getDataPoint(B2, A9)
=getDataPoint(B2, A10)
```

I'd then fill a column range with the formula in each cell to get the complete time series. The idea is to reduce the amount of validation required.

Ideally this would populate the cell when the spreadsheet is opened, or on click of a button.

What do I use to implement this, assuming it's possible and also aiming for fast processing times?

Assuming I can do this, can an add-in add another row onto the bottom of the range and insert the formula in there, e.g. on Monday, I have

```
=getDataPoint(B2, A7)
=getDataPoint(B2, A8)
=getDataPoint(B2, A9)
=getDataPoint(B2, A10)
```

and then on Tuesday, someone else has updated the time series on the server with Tuesday's data, so I retrieve it, see the extra value and want to extend the range automatically like this (where the date/time is in column A):

```
=getDataPoint(B2, A7)
=getDataPoint(B2, A8)
=getDataPoint(B2, A9)
=getDataPoint(B2, A10)
=getDataPoint(B2, A11)
```

My experience with VBA tells me that Excel is not going to like this, but I figure I don't know the Excel add-in paradigm well enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely confident this is what you're looking for, so please correct me If I'm wrong.

Once you define the `getDataPoint(Range, Range)` function in an Excel workbook, add the required references (if any) and save the file as Excel Add-In (.xlam). Dont forget to name the project in VBE properties, as you will need the name to add a reference to it later on. All projects default to *VBAProject* so it's difficult to differentiate them when adding references.

Once the add-in has been created, add it to your workbook through *Options* >> *Add-Ins* >> *Excel Add-ins*. Add also a reference to your project through *Tools* >> *References* in VBA Editor.

Your function can now be called like any of the built-in functions: `=getDataPoint(B2, A7)`.

FYI, you can get the calling range in your function through the `Application.Caller` property.

Note:

I'm using Excel 2010 so the options menu might be slightly different than yours.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I pretty much knew that already, what I am asking is whether all those function calls can work on the same data, which the add-in can also do stuff with via button events from buttons i put on the add-in ribbon.

Comment: Thought so. :) In a few words, yes it can. The addin holds the function(s) which do all the work - you only need to pass in arguments and expect the returned outcome, like any of the built-in functions. As for the ribbon button, I presume the button will point to a Sub in a standard module of the workbook which in return will point to the function within the add-in once a reference to the addin has been added.

Comment: I want the button, the button Sub, and all the functions to be in the add-in, so it can be installed in one hit and not require any coding in the spreadsheets it's used with. The idea I'm trying to convey is that the add-in gets the time series from a server when the button is clicked, and then the data from the server appears in the spreadsheet via the functions, displaying the bits of the time series that the spreadsheet owner specified when entering the functions.